# Optimize IIS for ASP.NET throughput

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an asp.net mvc app hosted in IIS that is 100% asp.net - it doesn't serve any razor pages or static files.

Can I tweak IIS settings in any way to optimize for asp.net throughput given that I don't serve any UI or static files?

Note I am stuck with IIS/MVC for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link for [Optimizing IIS Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050(v=bts.70).aspx)

Note that you should also tweak the application pool that your application uses. See [Managing, Tuning, and Configuring Application Pools in IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx) for guideline.